# How to use keras.utils.multi_gpu_model with custom subclassed Keras models

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am using the Keras Subclassing API to create a custom model. I tried to parallelize my model using:

```
parallel_model = keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(subclassed_model, gpus=num_gpus)
```

However I encountered the following error:

```
line 203, in multi_gpu_model
    for i in range(len(model.outputs)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

After, reading the docs in more detail, I noticed the following:

> In subclassed models, the model's topology is defined as Python code(rather than as a static graph of layers). That means the model's topology cannot be inspected or serialized. As a result, the following methods and attributes are not available for subclassed models: `model.inputs` and `model.outputs`.

So how can I train subclassed models on multiple GPUs? Have in mind that I am only interested in data parallelization.

Comment: This is just an idea, but you could try to define `inputs` and `outputs` yourself in your subclassed model. e.g. `self.outputs = someoutput`